# Detecting the type of implementation of exception handling in C++

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, mingw, mingw-w64

The C++ standard defines how exceptions must behave from a user perspective, but leaves it up to the compiler's developers how this is implemented. There are various types found in the field: DWARF, SJLJ, Itanium, SEH... Which one is used is not always well documented by the developers, except for MinGW and MinGW-w64, for which there is a dedicated downloadable tool chain for the different EH types.

The question is: what are the possibilities to detect the underlying EH implementation at runtime or a build time?

Comment: Compile a test sample with the toolchain in question and examine the resulting assembly, I suppose. The question is: why do you care? What would you do differently depending on the answer?

Comment: Isn’t the answer, such as it is, to use the usual implementation-identification macros and consult their documentation?

Comment: @DavisHerring The documentation can be a source of information, but too often it is not helpful. For instance, the LLVM documents which are supported, but not which are activated in the binaries available on the project page. The Qt SDK installer can install MinGW-w64 automatically, but doesn't provide any details about the flavor installed. The MinGW-w64 project provides SEH and SJLJ, and Qt actually provides SEH, but it is not documented explicitly. Qt seems to provide also a MinGW 32bit SEH.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I am investigating the migration of a project from MinGW-w64 SJLJ to SEH because of a bug in the former, and trying to find out what is standard and/or recommended. What other compilers are using would be helpful in this context. Since the documentation too often doesn't help, I am trying to find a "technical" way to find out. Disassembling is of course an option, but I was hoping for something easier, like checking between little and big endian, which can be done within the program itself.